# Running mySQL Statement results in nothing returned

Tags: mysql

So I am doing homework for mysql class and I am having a hard time understanding why my code is bringing back no data, it runs but returns nothing when I know that data that meets the criteria exists. Please help. Here is my code:

```
SELECT vendor_id
     , SUM(invoice_total) AS invoice_gt
     , AVG(invoice_total) AS invoice_avg
     , COUNT(invoice_id) AS invoice_qty
  FROM invoices
 WHERE "invoice_avg" > 300
 GROUP 
    BY vendor_id
 ORDER 
    BY "invoice_avg" DESC
```

Comment: can u show some data that meet this criteria?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the WHERE "invoice_avg" > 300 I return 34 rows with data that includes values that are greater than 300 in the invoice_avg column

Comment: You need to use HAVING instead of WHERE.

Comment: `"invoice_avg"` is a string. It won't ever be greater than 300. Try removing the quotes (or use backticks as needed instead of double quotes). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql for  more.

Comment: Note that depending on your settings for [ANSI_QUOTES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes), `"invoice_avg"` will be treated as a constant string or column name. However - If `ANSI_QUOTES` were enabled, you should get an error message for this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an aggregated column in the WHERE clause.
Use it in a HAVING clause which is evaluated after the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT vendor_id, SUM(invoice_total) AS invoice_gt, AVG(invoice_total) AS invoice_avg, COUNT(invoice_id) AS invoice_qty
FROM invoices
GROUP BY vendor_id
HAVING invoice_avg > 300
ORDER BY invoice_avg DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, marked it new to using the platform besides google searches so I appreciate the heads up

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes and try

```
USE ap;
SELECT vendor_id, SUM(invoice_total) AS invoice_gt, AVG(invoice_total) AS 
invoice_avg, COUNT(invoice_id) AS invoice_qty
FROM invoices
WHERE invoice_avg > 300
GROUP BY vendor_id
ORDER BY invoice_avg DESC
```

Comment: It says that there is "Unknown column 'invoice_avg' in 'where' clause